# What is wrong with the below code ? Expected X modified by thread Func 1 followed by X modified by thread Func 2

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, pthread-join

While studying multithreading, I wrote following code but no output observed on screen. What am I doing wrong here ? I expected output as follows:

```
X modified by threadFunc 1
X modified by threadFunc 2
```

but nothing is seen on the screen, and the program does not exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t globalMutex[2];
pthread_cond_t globalCondVar[2];

void *threadFunc1(void *args)
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(&globalMutex[0]);
   pthread_cond_wait(&globalCondVar[0], &globalMutex[0]);
   printf("X modified by threadFunc 1\n");
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalMutex[0]);
}

void *threadFunc2(void *args)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&globalMutex[1]);
    pthread_cond_wait(&globalCondVar[1], &globalMutex[1]);
    printf("X Modified by threadFunc 2\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalMutex[1]);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[2];

    pthread_mutex_init(&globalMutex[0], NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&globalMutex[1], NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&globalCondVar[0], NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&globalCondVar[1], NULL);

    pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, threadFunc1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, threadFunc2, NULL);

    pthread_cond_signal(&globalCondVar[0]);
    pthread_cond_signal(&globalCondVar[1]);

    pthread_join(thread[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(thread[0], NULL);

    pthread_cond_destroy(&globalCondVar[0]);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&globalCondVar[1]);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&globalMutex[0]);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&globalMutex[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably signal too soon. Throw in a sleep() before main() signals.

Comment: Also, have the thread functions return something

Comment: What @BjornA. says.  Wait a bit, or replace the condvars with semaphores.

Answer (score 1):

Condition variables are *not* events. They are designed to be used with actual boolean conditions protected by mutexes.

```
   (Init)
   condition = false

   (Signal)
   lock mutex
   condition = true
   signal condvar
   unlock mutex

   (Wait)
   lock mutex
   while not condition:
       wait condvar
```

This is the standard way of using condition  variables.